# Generate categorised data set from list in O(n)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to generate a data set with the following structure from a list of items with properties `prop1` and `prop2`:

`result[p1][p2] => list of item with prop1=p1 and prop2=p2`

I have been able to do it in O(n2) with:

```
result = {
    item.prop1: {
        item.prop2: [
            i
            for i in item_list
            if i.prop1 == item.prop1 and i.prop2 == item.prop2
        ]
    }
    for item in item_list
}
```

But haven't been able to find a way to do it in less time. Is it possible to achieve this in O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only have to iterate over the items once:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for item in item_list:
    result[item.prop1][item.prop2].append(item)
```

Comment: That won't quite work.  You need to use `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`.  In your version, `result[item.prop1]` will be a list, so trying to access `result[item.prop1][item.prop2]` will likely fail.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I overlooked that it was a 2d matrix. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a `dict` (as opposed to a `defaultdict`):

```
result = {}
for item in item_list:
    result.setdefault(item.prop1, {}).setdefault(item.prop2, []).append(item)
```